# Computed column using aggregate only returning 1 or 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

MS SQL Server 2016

I need to find out, for a grouping, how many rows are of the same integer value and what percentage of the total it is (over a certain % indicates user error in a system). This is part of a CTE that is referenced later on. Base data is structured as `CUSTOMER`, `PRODUCT`, `QUARTER`, unique integer values, and `PRODUCT_COUNT`. My query:

```
ISSUES AS(
SELECT 
    CONCAT(CUSTOMER,PRODUCT,QUARTER) AS CUST_PROD_QTR,
    MAX(PRODUCT_COUNT) AS HIGHEST_COUNT,
    SUM(PRODUCT_COUNT) AS TOTAL_COUNT, 
    MAX(PRODUCT_COUNT)/SUM(PRODUCT_COUNT) AS PERC_SAME_INT
FROM ALL_FORECAST
GROUP BY CONCAT(CUSTOMER,PRODUCT,QUARTER)
HAVING SUM(PRODUCT_COUNT)>1 AND MAX(PRODUCT_COUNT)/SUM(PRODUCT_COUNT) > 2/3)
```

`PERC_SAME_INT` seems to only return 1 or 0. Is this due to something structural in the code? I need to find a way to limit only for the grouping that has `MAX(PRODUCT_COUNT)/SUM(PRODUCT_COUNT) > 2/3`.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in this statement:

```
HAVING SUM(PRODUCT_COUNT)>1 AND MAX(PRODUCT_COUNT)/SUM(PRODUCT_COUNT) > 2/3)
```

In T-SQL, [if an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

To evaluate correctly, you need to cast the dividend or divisor to a floating point, e.g.:

```
HAVING SUM(PRODUCT_COUNT)>1 AND (1.0 * MAX(PRODUCT_COUNT))/SUM(PRODUCT_COUNT) > 2.0/3.0)
```